# Getting NativeCommandError while trying to clone a git repository from Powershell running in Windows 22H2

Tags: git, powershell

Try to create a clone of git repository from a Powershell script (OS: Windows 22H2) using below command:

**git clone ssh://git@xxx.git $path**

but getting below error:

*git : Cloning into 'path'...
At line:13 char:9

- ```
      git clone ssh://git@xxxx:7999/xxx ...
  ```
- ```
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Cloning into 'D...d_Bitbucket'...:String) [], RemoteException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError*

Comment: Personally I've successfully used the `$env:GIT_REDIRECT_STDERR = '2>&1'` workaround.

Comment: Thanks zett42, "$env:GIT_REDIRECT_STDERR = '2>&1'" helped me.